# Given a list of numbers, how do you create all the combinations of sums and return a list of those sum

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

Let us suppose that we have a list of numbers [1,2,3] and we have to append all the possible combinations of sum of elements in an array and return that array?

how to get the following sums

```
1 = 1 (the first element so simply add it to the ans array)
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1 + 3 + 2 = 6
2 = 2 (second element so simply add it to ans array)
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
2 + 1 + 3 = 6
2 + 3 + 1 = 6
3 + 1 = 4
3 = 3 (third element so simply add it to ans array)
3 + 1 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
3 + 1 + 2 = 6
3 + 2 + 1 = 6
```

So our final array will look like [1,3,4,6,6,2,3,5,6,6,3,4,5,6,6]

Comment: Why is `1 + 2 + 3 = 6` and `1 + 3 + 2 = 6` the name numbers in different order included, but `1 + 3 = 4` and `3 + 1 = 4` not both included?

Comment: Is the order significant?

Comment: yes the order should be significant. So that it can be applied on strings as well.

Comment: I tried backtracking but just cant wrap my head around how to solve it? It looks similar to generating all the sub sequence of the list of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [sum(p) for n in range(1, len(nums)+1) for p in itertools.permutations(nums, n)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

If you want to see exactly what `permutations` is doing rather than just seeing the final sums, you can do fun things with `map` and `join`:

```
>>> [f"{'+'.join(map(str, p))}={sum(p)}" for n in range(1, len(nums)+1) for p in itertools.permutations(nums, n)]
['1=1', '2=2', '3=3', '1+2=3', '1+3=4', '2+1=3', '2+3=5', '3+1=4', '3+2=5', '1+2+3=6', '1+3+2=6', '2+1+3=6', '2+3+1=6', '3+1+2=6', '3+2+1=6']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools`:

```py
import itertools

nums = [1,2,3]
results = []

def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return [a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n)]
        
for i in range(len(nums)):
    results.append(split(list(map(sum,itertools.permutations(nums,i+1))),len(nums)))

results = zip(*results)
results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results)))

print(results)
>>> [1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of a recursion problem.

To solve this out you need a function that call itself and will stop at given criteria.

```js
const getResults = (numbers, usedNumbers, results) => {
  if (usedNumbers.length >= numbers.length) return;

  numbers.forEach(number => {
    if (usedNumbers.includes(number)) return;

    const result = usedNumbers.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, number);
    console.log(`${[...usedNumbers, number].join(' + ')} = ${result}`)
    results.push(result);
  });

  numbers.forEach(number => {
    if (! usedNumbers.includes(number)) getResults(numbers, [...usedNumbers, number], results);
  })
};

const numbers = [1,2,3];
const results = [];
numbers.forEach(number => {
  results.push(number);
  console.log(`${number} = ${number}`)
  getResults(numbers, [number], results);
});

console.log(results);
```